# Reading mbox files with mbox Python module

Tags: python, mbox

Good afternoon, I'm working on a kind of spam filter in Python, and I've downloaded some spam and harm emails from this corpus

https://spamassassin.apache.org/publiccorpus/

This is the code I made to read the mbox files

```
import os
import mailbox
import sys
import pprint

print("Reading emails:")

for mbox_file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()+"/spam"):

    print("Processing "+mbox_file)
    mbox = mailbox.mbox(mbox_file)

    for message in mbox:
        print(message['from'])
```

The thing is that apparently it does not recognize the files, because it never reads anything at all. I create a separate .mbox file, copying the contents of one of the files and it readed perfectly. I Also try reading the files with read() and throws an error message that the file does not exist. I do not know what I'm missing, any help would be nice. Thanks for your time